# How to set the row in a table layout?

Tags: android

So far, I have code that dynamically creates my table within a horizontal scrollview. I want each item to appear in the same y location and so that you can only see one at a time. Right now, each column gets set, but the visual is like a staircase, where the next row is underneath and only moved over about 50px. Is there a way to force each column to take up the entire screen width? Also, can you set the row that the content appears in?

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.contentTable);
    for(int i=0;i<itemIndexes.size();i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tr.setLayoutParams(lp);
            if(globals.myHitetItems.get(itemIndexes.get(i)).image!=-1)
            {
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                    iv.setImageResource(globals.myHitetItems.get(itemIndexes.get(i)).image);
                    iv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(i));
                tr.addView(iv);
            }
            else
            {
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
                iv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(i));
                tr.addView(iv);
            }
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(globals.myHitetItems.get(itemIndexes.get(i)).name);
                tv.setTextSize(20);
                tv.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(i));
            tr.addView(tv);

            tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(globals.myHitetItems.get(itemIndexes.get(i)).content);
                tv.setTextSize(20);
                tv.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(i));
            tr.addView(tv);
        tl.addView(tr);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have use the `TableLayout` and now you want each cell to consume appropriate same size throughout the table respectfully by comparing itself via row and column.

So, you have to set **WEIGHT** to each item and specify weight value = **"1.0"** or below it.